# Remove dash borders and highlighting

Tags: unity, launcher

I am using the [Arc theme](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme). To make things look better I want to remove the border around the dash as well removing the highlighting. Is this somehow possible to do?

See this screenshot for a visualization of my idea:

[image]

Comment: Now Canonical is moving to Gnome.... Great! Finally we have the ability to easily tweak the shells appearance :)